# Snap Inkscape not using window colours from theme

Tags: themes, customization, gtk3, inkscape

I just installed `Inkscape` from the `Ubuntu Software`. When I opened, it has an old look on all of its walls. It reminds me of Windows 98. I have Materia theme running and every other app is taking colours from it. I am ok with the current instance, but it would be a bonus if I can fix it to take colours from the theme.

[image]

I use 18.04. Thanks.

Edit :

Works fine with Yaru and Yaru dark themes

Answer (score 0):

Snaps use the Desktop theme only if there's a snap version of the theme available. If you're using a different theme, snaps revert to the default theme.

Comment: I see. Is there anything I can do in this case ?

Comment: 1. Do not use the snap version of the app. Install the one from normal repos or ppa. 2. Use a system theme from the ones that are available for snap.

Comment: Is there any way to tell about a fallback, in index.theme ?

Comment: I am also having this issue. At first I installed Inkscape from Ubuntu Software and all was well. However, after a few days the theming changed to Gtk2 and Inkscape looked awful. I uninstalled the snap version and installed the PPA version instead. If you would like to check it out, here is the link: http://www.theubuntumaniac.com/2019/01/install-inkscape-0924-on-ubuntu-1804.html